# Android get 1st result and copy from google search(automatic)

Tags: java, android

I want a code to search to google engine for songs via zippyshare . For example the keyword will be "inna sun is up zippyshare" and the first result is  this url www32.zippyshare.com/v/55151563/file.html . i want to retrieve the code 55151563 from the the 1st result of google.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not write the code for you, but I can tip you to the right approach.

Get the url using String search = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + string_to_search;

Download the webpage using URL, InputStream and OutputStream. Check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog).

Read the file and find the first instance of zippyshare.
   Here you can read about [xml](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=30363) parsing

Comment: could you code it for me ?? I will pay you of course via Paypal.